# Color specific date in mat-date-range-input angular 10

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker, mat-datepicker

I'm currently working on a project that involves using Angular Material's MatDatePicker (range Selection)  component to display a calendar with custom styling for specific dates. I've encountered an issue while trying to apply custom CSS classes to certain calendar cells based on specific conditions.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-3 date-picker" (click)="picker2.open()">
          <mat-label>start date</mat-label>
          <mat-date-range-input class="special-element" [rangePicker]="picker2" [dateFilter]="dateFilter">
            <input matEndDate
              [readonly]="true" (dateChange)="changeDate('endDate')">
            <input matStartDate (dateChange)="changeDate('startDate')"[readonly]="true">

          </mat-date-range-input>

          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-date-range-picker #picker2></mat-date-range-picker>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add .`mat-calendar-body-cell-container` `css` declaration in your global
`styles.css`.

```
.mat-calendar-body-cell-content {
  color: white;
}


.mat-calendar-body-cell-container {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

[example of a datepicker with custom color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16Wi1.png)

Edit:

What you can do is the following:

```
export class YourComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  range =  new FormGroup({
    start: new FormControl(), end: new FormControl()
  });

  @ViewChild('picker2') picker!: MatDatepicker<Date>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.picker.dateClass = (date: Date) => {
      return {
        ['cell-class']: (date.getDate() % 2 === 0)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then on your global `styles.css` you can define `cell-class`.

```
.cell-class {
    background-color: red !important /* you must include important */
}
```

For this example, it applies color to all even days.

Reference: [MatCalendarCellClassFunction](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api#MatCalendarCellClassFunction)

Comment: i actually want to color specific dates , not the calendar

Comment: I have edited my answer. So the function accepts and object where the keys are class names and the value is boolean. So you can create your own logic to color specific dates.